# How to get Work and Education information from facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

How can i get Work and Education information plus cover from facebook.

I got other details with this function

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
if (user != null) {
        fbName=user.getName();
        fbId=user.getId();
        String email = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");
        }
    }
```

But i am unable to get Education info and work info?

Comment: Have you asked for those permissions?  And what is the actual request you are sending to get the fields?

Comment: i did not and i don't know how to ask or send request form work or eduction info?

Answer (score 2):

I made sure I asked for the appropriate permissions

```
    LoginButton lb = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    lb.setReadPermissions("user_work_history", "user_education_history");
```

Then I did a me request to get data

```
            Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request r = Request.newMeRequest(s, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {

                    }
                }
            });
            r.executeAsync();
```

user.getProperty("work") and user.getProperty("education") both give data then.